# Log-measure of uncertainty

Tags: entropy, moments, uncertainty

I would like to investigate if the following quantity has already a well-known meaning in statistic:

$$G_{\eta}(X) =\frac{1}{\eta} \log\Biggl[1 + \lim_{N\to +\infty}\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{\eta^n}{n!}\mathbb{E}\bigl[(X -\mathbb{E}[X])^n\bigr]\Biggr] $$

where $X$ is a stochastic variable. I think than in general, for $\eta > 0$ higher $G(X)$ corresponds to higher entropy of $X$. But I'm not sure whether this last statement is true, and neither how to show it.
the idea of entropy comes from

$$\frac{1}{\eta}\log \mathbb{E}[e^{\eta X}] = \mathbb{E}[X] + \frac{1}{\eta}\log \mathbb{E}[e^{\eta (X - \mathbb{E}[X])}] = \mathbb{E}[X] + G_{\eta}(X)$$

considering that $\frac{1}{\eta}\log \mathbb{E}[e^{\eta X}]$ is strictly connected to the dual of the entropy maximization problem.

Comment: You seem to have used $n$ as an index and as a limit variable (also the sum upper range is suspicious). Also, where does this come from?

Comment: This expression is very nearly the [cumulant generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant).

Comment: Thanks Alex R. It was a mistake. Thanks Whuber for pointing out the cumulant generating functions. Seems to be what I was looking for.